# Does the HTTP Request need to match the request method and the url?

Tags: spring-boot, http, httprequest

When I execute an HTTP request to the Backend, does the request method and the URL need to match, or is the URL enough?

Example (Backend written in Spring Boot): 
I have a GetMapping and a DeleteMapping with the same value (path). If I now make a request from the Frontend: `axios.delete('/v1/${var}')`. Does Spring Boot now know which mapping to use, or should I specify the URL.

My personal preference would also be, if it would work, to specify the URL anyway for better readability, just wanted to know if this would work

Comment: What is in `${var}`? Not knowing anything about your routing, yes in general you'll have to include your routes, unless you only have one base route with different methods.

Comment: @tobiv Doesn't matter what's in `${var}`. The URL in the Backend looks like this: `/v1/{tournament}` and there are Two Endpoints with the same URL but with different Mappings. Does Spring Boot then know which endpoint to take?

Comment: In that case yes, it can tell by the request method (`axios.delete`). `/v1/${var}` is already the full URL in that case.